# Unexpected token : using a JSONP request

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve the imdb rating of a movie through the omdbapi.

Myy function looks like this,

```
movieAdd.imdbRating($scope.movieListID.imdb_id)
  .then(function(response){
  console.log (response)
})
```

And my service looks like this,

```
function httpPromise (url) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    method:'JSONP',
    url: url
  })
    .success(function(data){
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}

service.imdbRating = function(id_imdb){
  return httpPromise(
    'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=' + id_imdb + '&plot=short&r'
  )
};
```

But in my console I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error in the JSONP output,

```
{"Title":"Warcraft","Year":"2016","Rated":"N/A","Released":"10 Jun 2016","Runtime":"N/A","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Fantasy","Director":"Duncan Jones","Writer":"Duncan Jones (screenplay), Charles Leavitt (screenplay), Chris Metzen (story)","Actors":"Travis Fimmel, Ben Foster, Paula Patton, Toby Kebbell","Plot":"An epic fantasy/adventure based on the popular video game series.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTgxMDAzNzMyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIwMTgxNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"N/A","imdbVotes":"N/A","imdbID":"tt0803096","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not JSONP.

Comment: Yea looks like it. Changing to `JSON` removes that error, but introduces a new one. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0803096&plot=short&rcallback. Method JSON is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.`

Comment: As a side note you do not need to wrap your `$http` call in a promise. it returns promises directly. just do `return $http();`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma right. if the api you're requesting from doesn't support CORS or JSONP, you can't get it using client-side javacript alone.

Comment: Note that for JSONP you need to specify to angular which parameter the api expects a callback parameter in. For example, by adding `&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` to the url. angularjs will automatically fill in `JSONP_CALLBACK`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Error with theMovieDB's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940602/angularjs-error-with-themoviedbs-api)

Comment: Hm, I thought I tried adding the callback, but I guess I tried it wrong. Got it working now.